# How to check if particular check box is checked in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Based on the checkbox I have to modify my JSP contents.How should I check if particular checkbox is checked or not.As far I have tried:

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when flag="${idName==true}">
      contents
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
      alternate contents
 </c:otherwise>
```

idName is the id of the checkbox lets say.

Updated:

```
 <% boolean flag=false; %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  if (document.getElementById("idName").checked) {
         <% flag=true %>
  }
 </script>
 <% if(flag==true) { %>
    content
 <% }
 else { %>
    alternate content
 <% } %>
```

But still its not working.

Comment: Understand that JSP works on server-side and JavaScript on client side. Now think again. Does what you want make sense? Would JSP EL allow you to use checkbox `id` in `${}`??

Comment: You can do this in javascript it seems. Onchanging the checkbox value if true show the first content, otherwise show the rest

Comment: @Ravi using taglib I can check whether flag is true or not.What's wrong with <c:when flag="${idName==true}">

Comment: Although I am still not able to solve this problem.I don't know how to check if checkbox is checked or not.One way seems like document.getElementById('idName') using javascript but is there another way in JSP itself.I am new to all these technologies so not able to understand clearly.

Comment: @user3505394 Put that line in your JSP and then server will tell you all that's wrong with that! JSP EL `${}` cannot access `idName` because checkbox and its state is present at client-side (in the browser) and EL executes on the server-side (and also before the JSP page is sent to the browser).

Comment: @Ravi I understood your point.I have changed my code but its still not working.Can you please tell  me if still I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Any comments? I am still stuck on this.